# FactoryGirl model's after_create not generating other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a model & a factory.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :emergency_contact, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :membership, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :email_settings, dependent: :destroy

  after_create :build_dependencies

  def build_dependencies
    build_membership
    build_emergency_contact
    build_email_settings
  end
  ...
end
```

When I run `FactoryGirl.create :user` the after_create runs, but the associated models aren't built and saved.

This is in contrast to the console where `User.create...` will build the other associations.

Comment: It's probably that `User.create` at the console is saving the `User` to the db, _then_ building the dependent records but not saving them and returning these unsaved dependencies. `FactoryGirl` is returning what was created (including being saved) in the database.  You should explain what you're trying to accomplish. The callback is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: @Gene scratch that previous comment, you were right, they're not being saved. Every User model has other models that always need to be created (but are not accessed often so stored in a different model) with it so a callback seemed smart. Is there another recommended way to achieve this?